# jQuery scroll to previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll

I need some help, theres a selection list and now you can scroll to next "shop" by clicking to the right. But cant get the left button to go to previous "shop". Theres a list of shops and you can scroll horizontal between each shop.

This is right button:

```
$(function() {
var scrollerwidth = 0;
var scroller = $("#scroller");

$("#scroller li").each(function() {
    scrollerwidth += $(this).width() + 1;
});
$("#scroller").width(scrollerwidth);
$("#scroller li:first-child").attr('id', 'current');

var iscroll = new IScroll('#countylist', { 
        eventPassthrough: true, 
        scrollX: true, 
        scrollY: false 
});

$("#scrollnext").click(function() {
    current = document.getElementById("current");
    current.id = "";
    //var next = $("#current").next();
    var next = current.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    next.id = "current";

        iscroll.scrollToElement(next);
    });

    }

)
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollnext" class="scrollnav next">
            <a href="Javascript:;"><span>&raquo;</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="countylist">
            <div id="scroller">
                <ul>
                    <? foreach ($counties as $i => $c): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a id="county_<?=$i?>" href="javascript:" class="stopped"><span><?=utf8_decode($c)?> (<?=count($stores_by_county[$c])?>)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <? endforeach ?>
                </ul>
```

What do I need to get it for previous?

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well?

Comment: next button is like this: <div id="scrollnext" class="scrollnav next"><a href="Javascript:;"><span>next</span></a></div>

Comment: yes please post html to understand correctly. As wild guess i will say on click event of #scrollnext you can save reference of current one ..and on click of scrollprevious you can use that event to scroll to.

Comment: Updated my entire code

Comment: I tried setting up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net but I couldn't get it to work. If you could get the **next** part working I'd be able to help you with the **previous** part.